# Using EntityManagerFactory and SessionFactory together at the same app for same database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, sessionfactory

Is it bad practice to use EntityManagerFactory and SessionFactory together at the same app for same database? Or it's better to use only one of them?

Answer (score 1):

`EntityManageFactory` is part of the JPA specification so it's more portable.
`SessionFactory` is Hibernate specific but the implementation is a subclass of `EntityManagerFactory` anyway.

Using one or the other (or both) depends on the requirements, how you create the factory and which API you prefer. Hibernate will return an implementation that's compatible with both interfaces anyway.